# setting jframe size with KeyEventDispatcher

Tags: java, swing, size, jframe, keyevent

This is my main class

```
package Apocalypse;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JFrame{
    private int xSize, ySize;

    public Main(){
        super("Zombie Apocalypse");
        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        xSize = (int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth();
        ySize = (int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight();
        setSize(xSize,ySize);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        KeyboardFocusManager kfm = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
        kfm.addKeyEventDispatcher(new MyDispatcher());
        add(new Level1());
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Main();
    }

    private class MyDispatcher implements KeyEventDispatcher{
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e){
            if(e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED){
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
                    System.out.println("It Worked");
                    setUndecorated(false);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

As you see in my KeyEventDispatcher class I want to setUndecorated to false to that you will be able to close the game but it doesn't work. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the frame is displayed you cannot change its decoration as [setUndecorated()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated%28boolean%29) throws `IllegalComponentStateException` in this case. To work around this you can create new decorated frame, move your content to it and dispose the old frame.